# Regex to capture sequence of digits not starting with a string

Tags: regex

I need to write a regex to capture all numbers being at least 9 digits and not
preceded by REQ or INC substrings.

Some examples of what I want:

```
1234567890 -> match -> 1234567890 
INC1234567890  -> not matching
REQ1234567890  -> not matching
IN1234567890  -> match -> 1234567890
```

What I tried so far:

```
(?<!(?:REQ|INC))(\d{9,})
```

But then my results are the following:

```
1234567890 -> match -> 1234567890 
INC1234567890  -> match -> 234567890
REQ1234567890  -> match -> 234567890
IN1234567890  -> match -> 1234567890
```

I tried playing around with `\b` but did not achieve anything.

Comment: Use `(?<!REQ|INC)\d{10,}` or `(?<!REQ|INC)\b\d{10,}`, or even `(?<!\d|REQ|INC)\d{10,}`. "longer than 9 digits" means "*ten or more*".

Comment: I need to capture 9 digits or more, thanks for the remark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
(?<!REQ|INC|\d)\d{9,}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uL3ZLm/1)

**Details**

- `(?<!REQ|INC|\d)` - no `REQ`, `INC` or digit allowed immediately on the left
- `\d{9,}` - nine or more digits.